# Error :: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'cereals' to data type int" in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to "Order by" my table by Id in Dynamic SQL, though it works with `Name` and `Description` (Both Type Nvarchar) as shown but not Working with `Id` (type INT),
Here is my Dynamic SQL Query

```
';With data AS (Select P.Id,
    P.Name,
    P.Description,
    P.Price,
    12 AS ActiveUsers,
    B.Name as BillingPeriod,
        CASE '+@SortField+'
                WHEN P.Name THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Name)
                WHEN Description THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Description)
                WHEN P.Id THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Id)   *****This Line Gives Error*****
            END rn '
     --- REST of The SP ---
```

The Line Gives Following Error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'cereals' to data type int.

I print SQL It shows ...

```
CASE P.Id
                WHEN P.Name THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Name)
                WHEN Description THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Description)
                WHEN P.Id THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Id)
                END rn From Products P
```

Please Help me with this, I am new to sql.

Comment: The first comparison in your CASE statement is to a "string" value (varchar or nvarchar I'll assume)

All subsequent comparisons will assume the same data type.

I'd suggest you put a CONVERT(varchar around the '+@SortField+' expression and the P.Id expression to make everything a string comparison.

Comment: Try WHEN Cast( P.Id as varchar(255)) THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Id)

Comment: Another tip I learned from https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/, if you are already building dynamic SQL instead having the CASE statement in the dynamic SQL; build that case statement OUTSIDE of the dynamic SQLand your final SQL has the WHEN part already built and SQL SERVER doesn't have to work as hard.

Comment: @Pete-S- I will keep that in mind, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the entire CASE expression with ...

```
';With data AS (Select P.Id,
    P.Name,
    P.Description,
    P.Price,
    12 AS ActiveUsers,
    B.Name as BillingPeriod,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+@SortField+')'
     --- REST of The SP ---
```

Comment: This will perform much better as well.

Comment: Thanks For Help, It Works better than previous.

Comment: @MAULIKDAVE

Glad I could help :)